# packet-sniffer can't sniff SIP(voip) packet

Tags: python, linux, sockets, udp, packet-sniffers

I want to build "SIP sniffer" for my project to alert incoming call from VoIP communication.I try to call from my smartphone to my notebook and check incoming packet by wireshark. I see all SIP-message ( INVITE , BYE , TRYING ). I know basic of SIP ,it use UDP port 5060.

Next, I use this code from http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/ <<--- last code , longest code ( I try to paste but I can't paste code in box ) run with Raspberry PI connect to notebook by LAN cable.

This program can sniff UDP packet, I check in wireshark it correct 90% ( IP address and IP destination not correct ) port and payload are correct.  I checking header from ethernet header ===> ip header ===> udp header
it not different from SIP-INVITE , they different only payload  ( check by wireshark ).

but i try to VoIP call to my notebook, It's not work , it never sniff 5060 or SIP packet ( one time i see outgoing call data : "sip:xxxx@linphone.org" )

Why i can sniff other but VoIP can't.

Sorry for my poor english.
thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

From the quick look , I see that your packets are UDP. 
But the python code only sniffs for TCP.

`#create an INET, raw socket s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)`

change socket.IPPROTO_TCP   to   socket.IPPROTO_UDP

Comment: not this code. it is longest code. 

raw socket s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(0x0003))

it sniff all in coming and outgoing packet

but i want only incoming UDP 

I try to change like your advice before but it sniff only MAC address,

thx for your advie.

Comment: Can you please change this in your code:
protocol = iph[6]
to  
protocol = ntohs(iph[6])


Can you put a print for iph[6] and check if its value is proper so that we can dismiss endianess issue.

Comment: First, put a print for iph[6] and see if it is 17 for udp
Second , put a print for socket.ntohs(iph[6])

Comment: Protocol : 17 change to Protocol : 4352 when I put socket.ntohs(iph[6])

and else print : Protocol other than TCP/UDP/ICMP

Comment: ok. I see socket.ntohs is not needed. You could see packets in tcpdump or Wireshark?

Comment: Wireshark , I can sniff NBNS packet , It's correct too in Wireshark
and I check format of NBNS. It same SIP-invite 
14 eth_header ==> 20 ip_header ==> 8 udp_header ==> different only payload

Comment: Can you comment all code in UDP section and just decode src port and dest port

Comment: it's too long , Where I can post it.

Comment: I post new comment

Answer (score 1):

```
#UDP packets
    elif protocol == 17 :
        u = iph_length + eth_length
        udph_length = 8
        udp_header = packet[u:u+8]

        #now unpack them :)
        udph = unpack('!HHHH' , udp_header)

        source_port = udph[0]
        dest_port = udph[1]
        length = udph[2]
        checksum = udph[3]

        print 'Source Port : ' + str(source_port) + ' Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' Length : ' + str(length) + ' Checksum : ' + str(checksum)

        h_size = eth_length + iph_length + udph_length
        data_size = len(packet) - h_size

        #get data from the packet
        data = packet[h_size:]

        print 'Data : ' + data

    #some other IP packet like IGMP
    else :
        print 'Protocol other than TCP/UDP/ICMP'

    print
```